# Android : Designing table layout for 60*30 size (predefined layout)

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am designing an application to record user information in android app. It records 60 min activity and for certain set of actions. In that each cell (Textview) records 1,0 or N/A activity for yes, no or no activity. 
So each text view is clicked 3 times to change between these values.

So each cell is important as I am going to record that information and export it to excel.

Currently, I have consider table layout with vertical and horizontal scrolling. But putting those many textviews (60*30) is affecting the performance of the application. But its working though.

I have tried with listview but it allows to select only one or multiple values. But in this case i have to change each and every value. I am also trying pagination, but not able to find proper information for this much big data and syncing information together.

so is it possible load each row one by one or each column keeping all components distinct?
Also is this a viable option or should I consider a webview with html5 development?

Please suggest automation or programmatic method to generate this view and how to remove performace issue error (main.xml has more than 80 views , bad for performance).